# API call infinite loop in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently trying to pass in a location for forward geocoding and can't figure out why my call seems to be triggering an infinite loop.

I'm trying to pass in the locations using a map and then use the response from the API elsewhere in my code.

Here's my data provider...

```
import React, {
  useEffect,
  useState
} from "react"

export const GeoCodeContext = React.createContext()

export const GeoCodeProvider = (props) => {
  const [latLong, setLatLong] = useState([])

  const getLatLong = (location) => {

    return fetch(`https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=${location}&key=MYKEY&limit=1`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(setLatLong)
  }

  return (
    <GeoCodeContext.Provider value={{latLong,getLatLong}}>
    {props.children}
    </GeoCodeContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Here's where the function is being called

```
import React, { useContext } from "react"
import {GeoCodeContext} from "./GeoCodeProvider"
import {LogContext} from "../divelog/DiveLogProvider"

export const MapRender = () =>{
    const {diveLogs} = useContext(LogContext)
    const {latLong, getLatLong} = useContext(GeoCodeContext)
    

    diveLogs.map(dl =>{
        //getLatLong(dl.location)
        //console.log(latLong) -- returns an endless log of api calls
    })

    

    return <h2>GeoCode Render</h2>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time your `MapRender` component renders, it calls `getLatLong` once for every dive log.

`getLatLong` ultimately triggers a call to `setLatLong`...

...which causes `GeoCodeProvider` to re-render...

...which causes `MapRender` (among other things) to re-render...

and we go back to the beginning of the loop.

Consider wrapping `MapRender`'s call to `getLatLong` in a call to the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) hook to avoid triggering it every render.

Comment: Please try giving a [qualified] solution rather than reiterating the problem. 'wrapping MapRender's call to getLatLong...' is just not useful.

Comment: The OP "can't figure out why my call seems to be triggering an infinite loop." The answer explains why the infinite loop is happening and suggests what to do to avoid the problem, with a link to relevant documentation. I encourage you to propose an edit rather than critiquing the answer in the comments.